# How can I configure and send email under cygwin without admin rights

Tags: bash, email, cygwin

I have a work machine running Windows 7 where I don't have admin rights. I have cygwin on it. It's a fairly complete install and includes tools like exim and email. I want to be able to send email from within a bash script using my work email credentials. Our work email is gmail-based.

All posts I found so far about configuring email under cygwin require running it as admin. Is there a way around it? Thank you

Comment: From  `email` manual I do not see anything that requires admin rights.